# Why Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: while upload image to server in android version 8 or higher

Tags: php, android, android-studio, file-upload

I Want to upload image to server using volley. image is uploading properly but it gives error in android version 8 or higher .
Error is
Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification:

```
    public void uploadMultipart() {
    if(filePath!=null) {
    try {
    String path = getPath(filePath);
    String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    Log.e("DATA",path+"\n\n"+uploadId);
    new MultipartUploadRequest(getContext(), uploadId, Const.UPLOAD_DOC_URL)// HERE ADD PHP URL NAME
    .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
    .setMaxRetries(2)
    .startUpload(); //Starting the upload
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Category Added successfully 111", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please select image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: What's your `UploadNotificationConfig`?

Comment: you are going to start service in background using sending notification from service. This error is because of notification is not sended successfull in oreo devices. make sure you have to bind notification channels inside it when os is oreo and above versions.

Comment: but i am not sending any kind of notification.i just want to upload image to server

Comment: @juniorandroid ,  your error indicates that you are using service for uploading image

Comment: i am using  'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1'  dependency